# como comparar dos array con una condicion

Tags: python, array, condiciones

tengo dos array, uno com 12 temperaturas y otro con numeros del 1 al 12 representando las temperaturas por meses, pero los array están separados es decir no son un dataframe o una tabla

```
temp = array([ 3.1,  3.3,  6.2,  9.2, 13.1, 15.6, 17.9, 17.5, 14.5, 10.7,  6.7, 3.7])
meses = array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

tengo que escribir un codigo que me devuelva los meses que tienen un valor mayor a la media del array temp, la media es 10.125, es decir deveria devolver esta lista:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

he probado a crear un df con ambos arrays transformandolos en series de esta forma:

```
values = {"temp": Temp_holland.astype(pd.Series),
"months": months.astype(pd.Series)}
pd.DataFrame(values)
```

pero me salta este error a pesar de haberlos transformado:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

que deberia hacer? se podria hacer simplemente usando booleanos? si es asi como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas pandas para nada, dado que cada que cada temperatura de `temp` está en el mismo índice que su mes en `meses`, un simple filtro boleano te basta:

```
import numpy as np

temp = np.array([ 3.1,  3.3,  6.2,  9.2, 13.1, 15.6, 17.9, 17.5, 14.5, 10.7,  6.7, 3.7])
meses = np.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])

res = meses[temp > temp.mean()]
```

> ```
> >>> res
> array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
> ```

Si quieres usar Pandas, podrías hacer algo como:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"meses": meses, "temp": temp})
```

si quieres filtrar las filas en las que la temperatura es mayor a la media:

> ```
> >>> df.loc[df.temp > df.temp.mean()].reset_index(drop=True)
>
>   meses   temp
> 0     5   13.1
> 1     6   15.6
> 2     7   17.9
> 3     8   17.5
> 4     9   14.5
> 5    10   10.7
> ```

o si quieres una serie con los números de los meses solo:

> ```
> >>> df.loc[df.temp > df.temp.mean(), "meses"].reset_index(drop=True)
> 0     5
> 1     6
> 2     7
> 3     8
> 4     9
> 5    10
> Name: meses, dtype: int64
> ```